# Find a pair of strings in a list in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, types

I just started learning Python and was struggling with this problem (and how to describe it in title):

Assume there is a name list like:

```
['Ben', 'Benjamin', 'Jenny', 'Alice', 'Alexandra', 'Alex', ...]
```

And I got a 'Name alias pairs' looks like:

```
[['Benjamin', 'Ben'], ['Alexandra', 'Alex'], ['Jennifer', 'Jenny'], ...]
```

How can I find if and which duplicated names are existed in the list?
E.g. **Ben, Benjamin** are duplicated, **Alex, Alexandra** are duplicated, BUT **Jenny** is not.

I was thinking about iterate through name list, see if there is any match in alias pairs. If so, iterate again and find whether the counter part exists as well. I am wondering if there is a better way to do that.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your list into a `set`:

```
names = frozenset(names)
```

Then for each pair you can easily check it:

```
for full, short in name_pairs:
    if full in names and short in names:
```

Comment: You could reduce the `if` further with `if {full, short} <= names:`. This works if the values of `full` and `short` are hashable, as they are in this problem.

Comment: Why `frozenset` rather than `set`?

Comment: @khelwood As a rule, objects should not have more functionality than needed.

Comment: @bipll That's not a real rule. By all means use frozen set if you prefer; I was just interested if there was a rationale.

Comment: @khelwood Here, at this fragment, I did not need to add more elements to the set; so I froze it.